# GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_BINDING OpenGL undefined

Tags: opengl

Looking through OpenGL documentation, I can see GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_BINDING, but the symbol remains undefined in my compile.  It's not in gl.h or glext.h.

Can someone locate it for me?

Edit: The following are defined:

GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_OFFSET, GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE, GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT

It's definitely described [here on the OpenGL website](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/), if you look under glGet.

Comment: I'd say it's a mystery!

Comment: which OpenGL version did you read the specs?

Comment: are you sure it's not GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER?

Comment: I'm just reading the documentation.  Is it wrong?  It says this: "GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_BINDING - returns a single value, the name of the buffer object currently bound to the GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER buffer binding point. The initial value is 0. See glBindBuffer."

Comment: skp, it's the OpenGl 4 Reference Pages, I've linked it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_BINDING`. The man page documentation is not the normative, authoritative documentation; that remains the OpenGL specification and the corresponding .spec files. And neither of these have such an enum.

I have since filed a bug report with the ARB, letting them know that they should have that enum. Because, as it stands, there's no way to query the buffer object bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`, and you're always supposed to be able to query any state you set.

Granted, not that filing a bug report with the ARB leads to any form of *action*...

Comment: Thanks Nicol.  The other 3 enums *are* defined, if you read the sentence again :).

Comment: @Robinson: Sorry about that; I was skimming.

Answer (score 1):

The enum you're after is GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_BUFFER.
It's naming is backward compared with the other enum's of similar purpose (Eg, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING).

See the [glGet enums](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGet.xml).

Comment: Thanks for that Adam.  Still, the documentation was screwed up in any case then.