# GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE not available for sampler?

Tags: opengl, textures

I was just writing a texture sampler object and noticed that `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE`, although available as a `glTex` parameter, is not selectable via the sampler.  Is this correct?  Is the reason it's missing to do with specifics of hardware implementation, or is it something that's generally done inside the shader these days?

Comment: That is correct, see pg. 539 of the [OpenGL 4.4 core spec.](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) for a list of all sampler parameters. Considering sampling stencil textures are a new feature (discussed on pg. 236 - 237) this may simply be an oversight in the specification.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Your answer is a little ambiguous. When you say correct do you mean glSamplerParameter does not have GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE or that it does not have HW support.

Comment: What is preventing GL from returning a uvec4 that has depth value in first 24 bits and stencil value in last 8 bits? Why are they separate?

Comment: When I said that it was correct, I was referring to the question in the title. There is no fundamental hardware issue here, for some reason this sampler state is per-texture *ONLY*, rather than per-sampler. Most other modern sampler states can be stored in a sampler object. Regarding `uvec4`, each component in a `uvec` is actually 32-bit so that does not make a whole lot of sense; you might as well pack it into a `uint`, but then you run into issues with formats like 32-bit Depth + 8-bit Stencil + 24-bit Padding. You would need an entire `uint` or `float` by itself to store the depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this correct?

What do you mean by "correct"? That's what the OpenGL specification says, so it is, by that definition, "correct".

If you're asking about how the hardware does it, that's obviously hardware-dependent. But the reason it's a texture parameter instead of a sampling parameter is that it fundamentally changes the nature of the texture.

In depth mode, the texture is read by the shader as a floating-point texture, of type `sampler2D` or whatever, depending on the texture's type. In stencil mode, it is read as an *unsigned integer* texture, with a sampler type `usampler2D` or whatever.

GLSL doesn't allow a shader to pick-and-choose whether a sampler gives floating-point or integer values.

Comment: Well that's interesting.  Thanks.  I used the term "correct" because I'm never really sure whether it's intended, I've made a mistake or they've made a mistake.  Recall http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710949/gl-texture-buffer-binding-opengl-undefined!